# Different results from Identical databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue where my live database (MariaDB) has the exact same data as my local(MySQL) but the following query is returning the same results but in a different order (I know im not the best at SQL so I'll apologise in advance):

```
SELECT
    `products`.*
    , CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) AS `order_date`
    , `category_product`.`category_id` AS `pivot_category_id`
    , `category_product`.`product_id` AS `pivot_product_id`
    , `count_activate`.`active_count`
    , IF( `count_activate`.`product_id` > 0, 0, 1 ) AS coming_soon
FROM
    `products`
    INNER JOIN
        `category_product`
    ON
        `products`.`id` = `category_product`.`product_id`
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            inventory.*
        FROM
            inventory
        INNER JOIN
            `booking_inventory`
        ON
            `inventory`.`id` = `booking_inventory`.`inventory_id`
        WHERE
            CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) > NOW()
        ORDER BY
            DATE( CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) )
    ) 
    AS 
        inventory
    ON
        `products`.`id` = `inventory`.`product_id`
    INNER JOIN
        `booking_inventory`
    ON
        `inventory`.`id` = `booking_inventory`.`inventory_id`
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(inventory.id) AS active_count
            , product_id
        FROM
            inventory
        INNER JOIN
            `booking_inventory`
        ON
            `inventory`.`id` = `booking_inventory`.`inventory_id`
        WHERE
            status_id = 1
        AND
        (
            stock    > 0
            OR stock = -1
        )
        AND 
            CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) > NOW()
        GROUP BY
            product_id 
    ) 
    AS 
        count_activate
    ON
        `count_activate`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
    WHERE
        `category_product`.`category_id` = 2
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `sites`
        INNER JOIN
            `product_site`
        ON
            `sites`.`id` = `product_site`.`site_id`
        WHERE
            `product_site`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
        AND 
            `status_id` = 1
        AND 
            `site_id` = 1
    )
    AND 
        `products`.`status_id` = 1
    AND 
        CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) > NOW()
    GROUP BY
        `products`.`id`
    ORDER BY
          `coming_soon` ASC
        , `order_date` ASC

    LIMIT     100
    OFFSET    0
```

can anyone tell me whats causing this?

regards

[image]

(left id External right is Local)

**EDIT**

Thanks for the daft comments below and the down vote, very helpful.... After some digging, I have found the cause yet not the answer. In the second JOIN (inventory) the date ordering isn't returning the same results. If I order by the inventory id, price, SKU I get the same results across local and external data but not using the date... would anyone know why?

regards

Comment: You can't sort it one time again after all that big query?

Comment: Can you pls provide some sample output to demonstrate the difference? Are the mariadb versions the same?

Comment: added image to question

Comment: sort order is not guaranteed unless you specify it in the query

Comment: why  are you reading the whole inventory.* when you're not bringing in any cols? Also you are selecting , products.*  twice

Comment: technically your query should return diff result as `now()` will vary between the two. try to replace `now()` for a constant to see if return same results

Comment: @Randy order by coming_soon, order_date ?

Comment: @Altons there days apart, don't worry about that

Comment: @Altons I need to order the course by date, but the courses that have no dates yet set, must go last as "coming soon". It works perfectly on my local, just not on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was down to the version/dbengine. The first left join has an order by in it, which I didn't realise didn't keep its order once used by the parent (depending on version/dbengine).

One way to overcome this is by setting a limit of `18446744073709551615` which forces the results to be stored in a temp table (or something, i know not what I speak!).

the other issue was inner join further down the query which forced to table to be reordered.

```
SELECT
    IF( `counter`.`product_id` > 0, 0, 1 ) AS coming_soon,
    bd.skill_level,
    counter.active_count,
    p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        p.*,
        booking_inventory.inventory_id,
        category_product.category_id,
        CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) as date
    FROM
        booking_inventory
    JOIN
        inventory
    ON
        inventory.id = booking_inventory.inventory_id
    LEFT JOIN
        products AS p
    ON
        p.id = inventory.product_id
    INNER JOIN
            `category_product`
        ON
            `p`.`id` = `category_product`.`product_id`
    WHERE
        CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) > NOW()
    AND
        `category_product`.`category_id` = 2
    ORDER BY
        date
    LIMIT
        18446744073709551615

)
AS
    p
LEFT JOIN
    booking_data AS bd
ON
    p.id = bd.product_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(`inventory`.`id`) AS `active_count`,
        `inventory`.`product_id`
    FROM
        `inventory`
    INNER JOIN
        `booking_inventory`
    ON
        `inventory`.`id` = `booking_inventory`.`inventory_id`
    WHERE
        `inventory`.`status_id` = 1
    AND
    (
        `inventory`.`stock` > 0
            OR
        `inventory`.`stock` = -1
    )
    AND
        CONCAT( `booking_inventory`.`year`, '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`month`, 2, '00' ), '-', LPAD( `booking_inventory`.`day`, 2, '00' ) ) > NOW()
    GROUP BY
        `inventory`.`product_id`
)
AS
    counter
ON
        `counter`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`
WHERE
EXISTS
    (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `sites`
    INNER JOIN
        `product_site`
    ON
        `sites`.`id` = `product_site`.`site_id`
    WHERE
        `product_site`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`
    AND
        `status_id` = 1
    AND
        `site_id` = 1
    )

GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    coming_soon,
    p.date,
    p.name
```